# Guard compiles watched assets - delete after tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, automated-tests, guard

I have the following in my Guardfile for a Rails project:

```
guard 'coffeescript', :input => 'app/assets/javascripts'
```

As a result, whenever I save a `foo.js.coffee` file, it compiles that file to a matching `foo.js`.

I want to keep this line in my Guardfile, because it can catch compilation errors. However, I don't want the `foo.js` files to remain in the project, so I'd like to know if there's a way for guard to delete them after the tests pass.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure really why you want to remove the file (or why not set the output folder to public/assets/javascripts), but you should be able to add a callback hook after tests run:

```
# Guardfile
guard 'rspec' do
  watch(...) { ... }

  callback(:run_on_modifications_end) do
    File.unlink('app/assets/javascript/foo.js')
  end
end
```

The '_end' hook should not run if the tests fail, so this should do what you want it to.